# Magento newsletter delivery speed for 5000 emails

Tags: email, newsletter

**How much time will magento take to send 5000 emails ?** with the default newsletter functionality.
I will be using a private server so i don't think there will be issues regarding the server performances.

Comment: As far as I know it send 20 Mails every 5 minutes so 5000/20*5/60 = 20 hours

Comment: Glad to help you out :) btw for mass newsletter like this I can recommend campaignmonitor. they got a really nice system with drag&drop responsive email templates and for 5000 mail it should still be cheep!

Answer (score 1):

There still might be a bottleneck with your email service provider if sending the newsletters via SMTP etc so I would always suggest hooking up to a service that is specifically built for mass mailing and can highly recommend Mailchimp and this Magento extension: [ebizmarts - MageMonkey](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-magemonkey-official-mailchimp-and-mandrill-integration.html)

Comment: +1. Server side, 50k emails could be delivered within minutes. But the real issue is ensuring they get delivered. The moment any large email service provider sees a flood from a single mail server, you'll immediately be grey listed/throttled/blacklisted. Using a commercial service is definitely recommend to ensure deliverability.